# How do I select the minimum value from a column in Mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to select from the database(Mysql) the moment(hour:minute:time) when the "temperature" field was lowest.

I have this:

```
string db = "select time from test.edata where data= '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd") + "' AND temperature.....";
```

In place of ..... should be the code needed.

How do I do this?

Comment: `select min(fieldname) from yourtable`?

Comment: I tried before posting my question.The syntax is wrong?I write :string db = "select time from test.edata where data= '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd") + "' AND temperature=(select min(temperature) from test.edata)";

Comment: mysql's date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`, not `yyyy:mm:dd`.

Comment: do a google search on how to use Aggregate functions and or write especially having emphasis on the word key word `Min` using MySql.. come on use the tools that are freely at your disposal.. google is one of them

Answer (score 1):

```
select time 
from test.edata 
where data= '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd") + "' 
order by temperature asc
limit 1
```